# I am developing a chat application using Flutter and used "Provider" package. but I'm getting this error

Tags: flutter, provider

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr1R3.png)

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this PostCard Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that PostCard is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }
  ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72047084/error-could-not-find-the-correct-provider-above-this-widget  , here this might help you

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, [you should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Click on the link below the question to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72811681/edit) it and replace the image with the code itself. Also, if possible, a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help users identify an adequate answer.